# How to choose --prefix for git svn clone

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

When I try `git-svn clone`, I get a warning:

> ```
> WARNING: --prefix is not given, defaulting to empty prefix.
>      This is probably not what you want! In order to stay compatible
>      with regular remote-tracking refs, provide a prefix like
>      --prefix=origin/ (remember the trailing slash), which will cause
>      the SVN-tracking refs to be placed at refs/remotes/origin/*.
> ```

`--prefix` is not mentioned in the git book [chapter on `git-svn`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git).
Various web pages recommend using `--prefix` ([tfnico](http://blog.tfnico.com/2013/08/always-use-git-svn-with-prefix.html), [objectparters](https://objectpartners.com/2014/02/04/getting-started-with-git-svn/)), but fail to explain what I should call it. Is it just an arbitrary name, or should it match something in the SVN repository?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should name it as you would a regular git remote, that is, pretend the SVN repository is a remote git repository; what name do you want to give it?  `--prefix=origin/` like the warning says is a safe choice unless you want a different origin remote.